# When I print from this code it returns as nonenone, Why does it do that and how can i fix it?

Tags: python, function, caesar-cipher

I am trying to create a ceasars cipher encoder but when I run this code:

```py
def Numbererplussome(Letter):
    if Letter.lower == "a":
        Numberee = 1
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "b":
        Numberee = 2
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "c":
        Numberee = 3
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "d":
        Numberee = 4
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "e":
        Numberee = 5
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "f":
        Numberee = 6
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "g":
        Numberee = 7
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "h":
        Numberee = 8
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "i":
        Numberee = 9
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "j":
        Numberee = 10
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "k":
        Numberee = 11
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "l":
        Numberee = 12
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "m":
        Numberee = 13
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "n":
        Numberee = 14
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "o":
        Numberee = 15
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "p":
        Numberee = 16
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "q":
        Numberee = 17
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "r":
        Numberee = 18
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "s":
        Numberee = 19
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "t":
        Numberee = 20
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "u":
        Numberee = 21
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "v":
        Numberee = 22
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "w":
        Numberee = 23
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower == "x":
        int(Letter)
        Letter = 24
        Numberee = Numberee - 23
    elif Letter.lower == "y":
        Numberee = 25
        Numberee = Numberee - 23
    elif Letter.lower == "z":
        Numberee = 26
        Numberee = Numberee - 23

def UnNumberer(Numberee, NewLetterrp):
    if Numberee == 1:
        NewLetterrp = "a"
        return NewLetterrp
    elif Numberee == 2:
        NewLetterrp = "b"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 3:
        NewLetterrp = "c"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 4:
        NewLetterrp = "d"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 5:
        NewLetterrp = "e"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 6:
        NewLetterrp = "f"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 7:
        NewLetterrp = "g"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 8:
        NewLetterrp = "h"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 9:
        NewLetterrp = "i"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 10:
        NewLetterrp = "j"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 11:
        NewLetterrp = "k"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 12:
        NewLetterrp = "l"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 13:
        NewLetterrp = "m"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 14:
        NewLetterrp = "n"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 15:
        NewLetterrp = "o"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 16:
        NewLetterrp = "p"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 17:
        NewLetterrp = "q"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 18:
        NewLetterrp = "r"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 19:
        NewLetterrp = "s"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 20:
        NewLetterrp = "t"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 21:
        NewLetterrp = "u"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 22:
        NewLetterrp = "v"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 23:
        NewLetterrp = "w"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 24:
        NewLetterrp = "x"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 25:
        NewLetterrp = "y"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 26: 
        NewLetterrp = "z"
        return NewLetterrp 
    





print("hello this is a ceasers cipher encoder please type your message below")
cstr = input()
print("the encoded message should be:")
for letter in cstr:
        print(UnNumberer(Numbererplussome(letter), ""), end="")
```

The output returns as
NoneNone
when I input "hi".

I understand why print outputs none in most scenarios but why does it happen when I am returning the variable that (should) have a value?

I tried to fix this but putting all of the functions into the print function but it didn't solve my issue.

How do I add value to my (appearently) valueless variable?

Comment: You probably want `Letter.lower()`.

Comment: You might want to read the docs on `ord()` and `chr()` function. It'll clean up all these conditions

Comment: Or, consider `Letter = Letter.lower()` at the start.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake: You forgot the parentheses`()` to call `.lower()` as a method on your string

Comment: The entire thing **can** be written with just one line so, it definitely doesn't need to be written with 50+ conditional statements. - `cipher = lambda n: "".join(chr((i+n-97)%26+97) if (i:=ord(c)) in range(97, 123) else c for c in input('> ').lower())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you wrote:

```
def Numbererplussome(Letter):
    if Letter.lower == "a":
```

Although the object `Letter` has a function called `lower`. You need to call the function by using `Letter.lower()` to get the return value, which is the lowered letter. If you just write `Letter.lower`, the interpreter will think that you are referring to the function itself rather than the lowered letter. And as the function is not a string and does not match any if statements, it will return None.

Updated code:

```
def Numbererplussome(Letter):
    if Letter.lower() == "a":
        Numberee = 1
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "b":
        Numberee = 2
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "c":
        Numberee = 3
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "d":
        Numberee = 4
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "e":
        Numberee = 5
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "f":
        Numberee = 6
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "g":
        Numberee = 7
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "h":
        Numberee = 8
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "i":
        Numberee = 9
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "j":
        Numberee = 10
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "k":
        Numberee = 11
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "l":
        Numberee = 12
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "m":
        Numberee = 13
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "n":
        Numberee = 14
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "o":
        Numberee = 15
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "p":
        Numberee = 16
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "q":
        Numberee = 17
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "r":
        Numberee = 18
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "s":
        Numberee = 19
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "t":
        Numberee = 20
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "u":
        Numberee = 21
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "v":
        Numberee = 22
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "w":
        Numberee = 23
        Numberee = Numberee + 3
        return Numberee
    elif Letter.lower() == "x":
        int(Letter)
        Letter = 24
        Numberee = Numberee - 23
    elif Letter.lower() == "y":
        Numberee = 25
        Numberee = Numberee - 23
    elif Letter.lower() == "z":
        Numberee = 26
        Numberee = Numberee - 23

def UnNumberer(Numberee, NewLetterrp):
    if Numberee == 1:
        NewLetterrp = "a"
        return NewLetterrp
    elif Numberee == 2:
        NewLetterrp = "b"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 3:
        NewLetterrp = "c"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 4:
        NewLetterrp = "d"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 5:
        NewLetterrp = "e"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 6:
        NewLetterrp = "f"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 7:
        NewLetterrp = "g"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 8:
        NewLetterrp = "h"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 9:
        NewLetterrp = "i"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 10:
        NewLetterrp = "j"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 11:
        NewLetterrp = "k"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 12:
        NewLetterrp = "l"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 13:
        NewLetterrp = "m"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 14:
        NewLetterrp = "n"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 15:
        NewLetterrp = "o"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 16:
        NewLetterrp = "p"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 17:
        NewLetterrp = "q"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 18:
        NewLetterrp = "r"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 19:
        NewLetterrp = "s"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 20:
        NewLetterrp = "t"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 21:
        NewLetterrp = "u"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 22:
        NewLetterrp = "v"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 23:
        NewLetterrp = "w"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 24:
        NewLetterrp = "x"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 25:
        NewLetterrp = "y"
        return NewLetterrp 
    elif Numberee == 26: 
        NewLetterrp = "z"
        return NewLetterrp 
    





print("hello this is a ceasers cipher encoder please type your message below")
cstr = input()
print("the encoded message should be:")
for letter in cstr:
        print(UnNumberer(Numbererplussome(letter), ""), end="")
```